# Golang WebSocket connection

Tags: http, go, websocket

I started learning Golang. And I have this project, where I need to stream some data from API via WebSocket connection, and print it in the console.

And the thing I don't understand - I have a URL, so I can make a request on it (through net/http package), but how can I upgrade it to WebSocket?

Can I make it only using pure Golang? I couldn't find appropriate information on the internet. All examples use JS, or they make it too complicated (like building some app, which I don't want to, and simply can't follow along, because of its complexity).

Comment: I searched for anything relatable, like golang websocket, golang api stream and so on. But all I found is just too complicated, or uses JS

Comment: I don't understand how you're having so much trouble finding any resources. Are any of the above links useful for your project?

Comment: Gorilla is a great library for WebSockets, and is used entirely with Golang. It supports clients and servers alike. I'm pretty sure there are no better (or simpler) options that using a library. By the way: A "WebSocket" connection will be from a web browser more often than not - hence all the JS clients you probably see.

Comment: are you talking about upgrading the connection? if so that is done at the server side, where you don't need javascript. At the client side, you probably need a front end, where javscript is used. I don't understand the idea of making a pure golang application.

Answer (score 0):

I got you. WebSocket has client side and server side. Most of the time people need run client side in browser. gorilla's websocket implementation supports both client and server. you can use it to dial your server. here is an example code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func main() {
    ws, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("ws[s]://localhost/path?query", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer ws.Close()

    for {
        // Read a message from websocket connection
        _, msg, err := ws.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
             return
        }

        fmt.Println(string(msg))

        // uncomment below if you need send message to remote server
        //if err = ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg); err != nil {
        //  return
        //}
    }
}
```

Here is the completed simple client and server example: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/echo

Answer (score 0):

use go websocket just like javascript:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/lxzan/gws"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    socket, _, err := gws.NewClient(new(WebSocket), &gws.ClientOption{
        Addr: "ws://127.0.0.1:3000/connect",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(err.Error())
        return
    }
    socket.Listen()
}

type WebSocket struct {
    gws.BuiltinEventHandler
}

func (c *WebSocket) OnMessage(socket *gws.Conn, message *gws.Message) {
    fmt.Printf("recv: %s\n", message.Data.String())
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).